# ASP.NET IsPostback return false even on button click

Tags: asp.net, post, ispostback

Why isPostback returns always false when I push the button ? (dev computer)

Did Someone met this kind of issue ? I don't understand what's wrong?

I created an other new form with a single button and it's the same issue.

But on the prod server, isPostback return true. Very strange.

Could it be a configuration problem ?

Any idea ?

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim a As String = ""

        Else
            Dim a As String = ""
        End If


    End Sub

    Protected Sub Connecter_bt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Connecter_bt.Click
```

' other code 
        End Sub

```
End Class

    <%@ Page Language="vb"  AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="CloudIS.Login"  %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

...
...

```
                        <form runat="server" id="login_form" class="smart-form client-form" action="Login.aspx">
                                <header>
                                    Connexion (<%=Request.UserHostAddress%>)
                                </header>
                                <fieldset>

                                    <section>
                                        <label class="label">E-mail</label>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="email" type="email" AutoCompleteType="email" ClientID="email" name="email" placeholder="Adresse Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                           
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Merci d'entrer votre email adresse</b></label>
                                    </section>

                                    <section>
                                        <label class="label">Mot de passe</label>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="password" type="password" ClientID="password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                        
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Entrez votre mot de passe</b> </label>
                                        <div class="note">
                                            <a href="javascript:alert('Bientôt disponible! Envoyez votre demande à support@cloudimpartial.com en précisant votre adresse mail de connexion;');">Mot de passe perdu?</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </section>

                                    <section>
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" checked="">
                                            <i></i>Rester connecté</label>
                                    </section>
                                </fieldset>
                                <footer>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Connecter_bt" runat="server"  Text="Connecter" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="ErrMsg" Visible="false" CssClass="ErrorMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </footer>
                            </form>
```

Comment: The button in the markup (aspx page) does not have a click event like `OnClick="Connecter_bt_Click"`.

Comment: Thank's, This doesn't explain why it works on the prod computer and not on dev computer.